# Why mktextfm-generated property list is different from default in TeXLive?

Tags: fonts, texlive

My setup: TeX Live, version 2014.20141024-2 (packaged with Debian 8 Jessie)

Save default PL:

```
$ tftopl cmr10 > cmr10.pl.old
```

Generate new TFM:

```
$ mktextfm cmr10
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input cmr10
This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (TeX Live 2015/dev/Debian) (preloaded base=mf)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/cm/cmr10.mf
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/cm/cmbase.mf)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/cm/roman.mf
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/cm/romanu.mf [65] [66]
[67] [68] [69] [70] [71] [72] [73] [74] [75] [76] [77] [78] [79] [80] [81]
[82] [83] [84] [85] [86] [87] [88] [89] [90])
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/cm/romanl.mf [97] [98]
[99] [100] [101] [102] [103] [104] [105] [106] [107] [108] [109] [110] [111]
[112] [113] [114] [115] [116] [117] [118] [119] [120] [121] [122])
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/cm/greeku.mf [0] [1]
[2] [3] [4] [5] [6] [7] [8] [9] [10])
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/cm/romand.mf [48] [49]
[50] [51] [52] [53] [54] [55] [56] [57])
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/cm/romanp.mf [36] [38]
[63] [62]) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/cm/romspl.mf
[16] [17] [25] [26] [27] [28])
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/cm/romspu.mf [29] [30]
[31]) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/cm/punct.mf [33]
[60] [35] [37] [39] [40] [41] [42] [43] [44] [46] [47] [58] [59] [61] [64]
[91] [93] [96]) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/cm/accent.mf
[18] [19] [20] [21] [22] [23] [24] [32] [94] [95] [125] [126] [127])
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/cm/romlig.mf [11] [12]
[13] [14] [15]) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/cm/comlig.mf
[34] [45] [92] [123] [124]) ) )
Font metrics written on cmr10.tfm.
Output written on cmr10.600gf (128 characters, 24096 bytes).
Transcript written on cmr10.log.
mktextfm: /usr/local/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/public/cm/cmr10.tfm: successfully generated.
/usr/local/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/public/cm/cmr10.tfm
```

First: mktextfm should not generate new TFM if one already exists. Second: compare old PL and new PL. They are supposed to be the same, but they are not. Why?

```
$ tftopl cmr10 | diff -u cmr10.pl.old -
--- cmr10.pl.old
+++ -
@@ -1,6 +1,3 @@
-(FAMILY CMR)
-(FACE O 352)
-(CODINGSCHEME TEX TEXT)
 (DESIGNSIZE R 10.0)
 (COMMENT DESIGNSIZE IS IN POINTS)
 (COMMENT OTHER SIZES ARE MULTIPLES OF DESIGNSIZE)
```

Comment: It will not make a new one if an existing TFM for the font exists in the appropriate place. In this case, that is probably `~/.texlive2014/texmv-var/fonts/tfm/public/cm/cmr10.tfm`. If you run the command again, it does not redo the work. As for the first question, why do you think they should be identical? The active code should be identical but, in general, these tools do not produce identical files. (Compare a run of `pltotf` followed by `tftopl`. You will not get an identical file back. But, the file will be identical when read by TeX because the differences will not be germane.)

Comment: @cfr in my texmf.cnf I have this: "TEXMFVAR = $TEXMFLOCAL". But what do you mean under "appropriate place"? TeXLive was installed from packages, and I didn't change anything.

Comment: Just that since you are using Debian's TL, it is possible they might be using a different default. I don't think this is likely. So `~/.texlive2014/texmf-var` is almost certainly right. But, just in case, I said 'probably' there. But, wherever it is, it will be in your home directory somewhere. `kpsewhich -var TEXMFVAR` will tell you where. Certainly, you will have non-standard values in `texmf.cnf` but I would expect the value of `TEXMFVAR` to still come out the same.

Comment: @cfr It's interesting to know the output of `mktextfm cmr10` on your installation

Comment: @cfr As you proposed, I did this: `tftopl cmr10 > cmr10.pl; pltotf cmr10.pl; tftopl cmr10 | diff -u cmr10.pl -` The diff shows that only SEVENBITSAFEFLAG is added. What for are FAMILY, FACE and CODINGSCHEME anyway?

Comment: I was thinking more of when you've created the `.pl` file using e.g. `fontinst` or by hand. Hence the order: `pltotf` *then* `tftopl`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23035/discussion-between-igor-liferenko-and-cfr).